# Read phone state permission added but still crashing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have added the permission of read phone state in the manifest of android studio but still the app is crashing and the error is:

```
9586-9586/com.tagtual.loopjexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tagtual.loopjexample, PID: 9586 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.tagtual.loopjexample/com.tagtual.loopjexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10821 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tagtual.trackd" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
   <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: on Android 6.0 ? if so, then use internet search .... if no ... then provide manifest file

Comment: Post your `manifext.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have actually found a solution, this problem persists only in phones which have android marshmallow, this update has a security issue, user has to manually allow what permissions the app will have.go to settings->apps->your app->permissions->enable required permissions. your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Is this permission in your manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tagtual.trackd" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: @parvezrafi Post all your manifest in your question with a style.

Comment: ok in the code must be an error, use try / catch or send us the code